# UITableViewCell Hit Area

Tags: ios, uitableview

I can't understand why I can't tap the far right of my table view cell. It seems like the hit area doesn't include the red area I've highlighted below. I've got buttons like a detail disclosure but i can only tap a small part of them.

[image: Hit Area]

**Is there a better way to implement this functionality?**

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure that this will work, but in

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Can you set:

```
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
```

This may prevent the far right area from only detecting cell selection touches.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I've selected this in the storyboard but I'll give it a go anyway.

Comment: ok, it was worth a try. Not sure what to suggest next, maybe override the hit test of the UITableViewCell to ignore touches and pass them to the super view.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you're going for, but you might have more success if you actually set those right-hand controls as the `accessoryView` of their respective cells, rather than adding them directly into the `contentView`.  The `accessoryView` is a built-in part of `UITableViewCell` that is designed specifically for this purpose; it will position the control on the right and handle the resizing of the cell's `contentView` for you.

You can read more about `UITableViewCell` anatomy in [this section of Apple's Table View Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html).